# How to create animated movie or gif from data of text file for Turkey map?

Tags: matlab

I'd like to create animated such as [animated daily map](http://aiuws.unibe.ch/ionosphere/gim.gif)

File structure:

- 1st column, year
- 2nd column, day of the year
- 3rd column, universal time(or hour)
- 4st column, latitude(grid)
- 5st column, longitude(grid)
- 6st column, value

Text file as follow:

```
2012 181 0 35 25 18.7
2012 181 0 35 30 18.7
2012 181 0 35 35 18.5
2012 181 0 35 40 18.1
2012 181 0 35 45 17.8
2012 181 2 35 25 18.2
2012 181 2 35 30 18.2
2012 181 2 35 35 18
2012 181 2 35 40 17.8
2012 181 2 35 45 17.7
2012 181 4 35 25 15.8
2012 181 4 35 30 16
2012 181 4 35 35 16.1
2012 181 4 35 40 16.2
2012 181 4 35 45 16.2
2012 181 6 35 25 14.5
2012 181 6 35 30 14.4
2012 181 6 35 35 14.4
2012 181 6 35 40 14.5
2012 181 6 35 45 14.9
2012 181 8 35 25 13.9
2012 181 8 35 30 15.3
2012 181 8 35 35 16.4
2012 181 8 35 40 17.3
2012 181 8 35 45 18.5
2012 181 10 35 25 16.6
2012 181 10 35 30 16.7
2012 181 10 35 35 16.9
2012 181 10 35 40 17.3
2012 181 10 35 45 17.9
2012 181 12 35 25 17.2
2012 181 12 35 30 18.4
2012 181 12 35 35 19.5
2012 181 12 35 40 20.3
2012 181 12 35 45 20.9
2012 181 14 35 25 19
2012 181 14 35 30 19.5
2012 181 14 35 35 20.7
2012 181 14 35 40 22.4
2012 181 14 35 45 24.5
2012 181 16 35 25 22.3
2012 181 16 35 30 22.8
2012 181 16 35 35 23.8
2012 181 16 35 40 25.1
2012 181 16 35 45 26.3
2012 181 18 35 25 25.1
2012 181 18 35 30 26.4
2012 181 18 35 35 27.5
2012 181 18 35 40 28.2
2012 181 18 35 45 28.8
2012 181 20 35 25 29.5
2012 181 20 35 30 30.1
2012 181 20 35 35 30.2
2012 181 20 35 40 29.9
2012 181 20 35 45 29.7
2012 181 22 35 25 27.6
2012 181 22 35 30 25.9
2012 181 22 35 35 24.3
2012 181 22 35 40 23.1
2012 181 22 35 45 22.3
2012 181 0 37.5 25 18.1
2012 181 0 37.5 30 18.1
2012 181 0 37.5 35 17.8
2012 181 0 37.5 40 17.3
2012 181 0 37.5 45 16.9
2012 181 2 37.5 25 17.4
2012 181 2 37.5 30 17.2
2012 181 2 37.5 35 17
2012 181 2 37.5 40 16.9
2012 181 2 37.5 45 16.8
2012 181 4 37.5 25 15.3
2012 181 4 37.5 30 15.3
2012 181 4 37.5 35 15.3
2012 181 4 37.5 40 15.3
2012 181 4 37.5 45 15.3
2012 181 6 37.5 25 13.7
2012 181 6 37.5 30 13.4
2012 181 6 37.5 35 13.3
2012 181 6 37.5 40 13.4
2012 181 6 37.5 45 13.9
2012 181 8 37.5 25 13.4
2012 181 8 37.5 30 14.6
2012 181 8 37.5 35 15.6
2012 181 8 37.5 40 16.5
2012 181 8 37.5 45 17.6
2012 181 10 37.5 25 16.6
2012 181 10 37.5 30 16.8
2012 181 10 37.5 35 17.2
2012 181 10 37.5 40 17.6
2012 181 10 37.5 45 18.2
2012 181 12 37.5 25 16.2
2012 181 12 37.5 30 17.4
2012 181 12 37.5 35 18.6
2012 181 12 37.5 40 19.3
2012 181 12 37.5 45 19.9
2012 181 14 37.5 25 18.4
2012 181 14 37.5 30 18.8
2012 181 14 37.5 35 19.6
2012 181 14 37.5 40 20.8
2012 181 14 37.5 45 22.2
2012 181 16 37.5 25 20.7
2012 181 16 37.5 30 21.2
2012 181 16 37.5 35 22.1
2012 181 16 37.5 40 23
2012 181 16 37.5 45 23.9
2012 181 18 37.5 25 22.9
2012 181 18 37.5 30 24.1
2012 181 18 37.5 35 25.1
2012 181 18 37.5 40 25.7
2012 181 18 37.5 45 26.1
2012 181 20 37.5 25 27
2012 181 20 37.5 30 27.6
2012 181 20 37.5 35 27.7
2012 181 20 37.5 40 27.5
2012 181 20 37.5 45 27.4
2012 181 22 37.5 25 26.3
2012 181 22 37.5 30 25
2012 181 22 37.5 35 23.7
2012 181 22 37.5 40 22.5
2012 181 22 37.5 45 21.6
2012 181 0 40 25 18
2012 181 0 40 30 17.8
2012 181 0 40 35 17.3
2012 181 0 40 40 16.7
2012 181 0 40 45 16.1
2012 181 2 40 25 16.7
2012 181 2 40 30 16.3
2012 181 2 40 35 16
2012 181 2 40 40 15.7
2012 181 2 40 45 15.6
2012 181 4 40 25 14.8
2012 181 4 40 30 14.6
2012 181 4 40 35 14.4
2012 181 4 40 40 14.2
2012 181 4 40 45 14.1
2012 181 6 40 25 12.7
2012 181 6 40 30 12.4
2012 181 6 40 35 12.2
2012 181 6 40 40 12.3
2012 181 6 40 45 12.7
2012 181 8 40 25 12.8
2012 181 8 40 30 13.9
2012 181 8 40 35 14.8
2012 181 8 40 40 15.7
2012 181 8 40 45 16.8
2012 181 10 40 25 16.4
2012 181 10 40 30 16.9
2012 181 10 40 35 17.4
2012 181 10 40 40 18.1
2012 181 10 40 45 18.6
2012 181 12 40 25 15.6
2012 181 12 40 30 16.7
2012 181 12 40 35 17.8
2012 181 12 40 40 18.5
2012 181 12 40 45 19.1
2012 181 14 40 25 18.1
2012 181 14 40 30 18.4
2012 181 14 40 35 18.9
2012 181 14 40 40 19.6
2012 181 14 40 45 20.6
2012 181 16 40 25 19.6
2012 181 16 40 30 20.1
2012 181 16 40 35 20.9
2012 181 16 40 40 21.6
2012 181 16 40 45 22.2
2012 181 18 40 25 21
2012 181 18 40 30 22.2
2012 181 18 40 35 23.1
2012 181 18 40 40 23.6
2012 181 18 40 45 23.9
2012 181 20 40 25 24.7
2012 181 20 40 30 25.3
2012 181 20 40 35 25.4
2012 181 20 40 40 25.3
2012 181 20 40 45 25.3
2012 181 22 40 25 25.2
2012 181 22 40 30 24.4
2012 181 22 40 35 23.3
2012 181 22 40 40 22.2
2012 181 22 40 45 21.1
2012 181 0 42.5 25 18.1
2012 181 0 42.5 30 17.8
2012 181 0 42.5 35 17.2
2012 181 0 42.5 40 16.3
2012 181 0 42.5 45 15.4
2012 181 2 42.5 25 16.2
2012 181 2 42.5 30 15.6
2012 181 2 42.5 35 15
2012 181 2 42.5 40 14.6
2012 181 2 42.5 45 14.3
2012 181 4 42.5 25 14.1
2012 181 4 42.5 30 13.7
2012 181 4 42.5 35 13.3
2012 181 4 42.5 40 13
2012 181 4 42.5 45 12.7
2012 181 6 42.5 25 11.8
2012 181 6 42.5 30 11.4
2012 181 6 42.5 35 11.2
2012 181 6 42.5 40 11.3
2012 181 6 42.5 45 11.8
2012 181 8 42.5 25 12.2
2012 181 8 42.5 30 13.3
2012 181 8 42.5 35 14.2
2012 181 8 42.5 40 15.1
2012 181 8 42.5 45 16.2
2012 181 10 42.5 25 16.2
2012 181 10 42.5 30 16.9
2012 181 10 42.5 35 17.6
2012 181 10 42.5 40 18.4
2012 181 10 42.5 45 18.9
2012 181 12 42.5 25 15.2
2012 181 12 42.5 30 16.3
2012 181 12 42.5 35 17.3
2012 181 12 42.5 40 18
2012 181 12 42.5 45 18.4
2012 181 14 42.5 25 18
2012 181 14 42.5 30 18.3
2012 181 14 42.5 35 18.6
2012 181 14 42.5 40 19
2012 181 14 42.5 45 19.5
2012 181 16 42.5 25 18.7
2012 181 16 42.5 30 19.4
2012 181 16 42.5 35 20.1
2012 181 16 42.5 40 20.6
2012 181 16 42.5 45 20.9
2012 181 18 42.5 25 19.5
2012 181 18 42.5 30 20.6
2012 181 18 42.5 35 21.5
2012 181 18 42.5 40 22
2012 181 18 42.5 45 22.3
2012 181 20 42.5 25 23
2012 181 20 42.5 30 23.4
2012 181 20 42.5 35 23.5
2012 181 20 42.5 40 23.5
2012 181 20 42.5 45 23.5
2012 181 22 42.5 25 24.5
2012 181 22 42.5 30 24.1
2012 181 22 42.5 35 23.2
2012 181 22 42.5 40 22.1
2012 181 22 42.5 45 20.9
```

How to make it on Turkey map?

I didn't succeed anything how to make it on map.

```
%Latitude = [35:2.5:42.5]
%Longitude=[25:5:45]
data = importdata('data.txt') ;
y = data(:,1) ;
d = data(:,2) ;
ut = data(:,3) ;
lat = data(:,4) ;
long = data(:,5) ;
t = data(:,6) ;
[c,ia,ib] = unique(ut) ;
for i = 1:length(c)
    X = reshape(long(ib==i),length(unique(long)),length(unique(lat))) ;
    Y = reshape(lat(ib==1),length(unique(long)),length(unique(lat))) ;
    Z = reshape(ut(ib==1),length(unique(long)),length(unique(lat))) ;
    pcolor(X,Y,Z)
    shading interp 
    %title(sprintf('Hour = %s',num2str(c(i))))
    drawnow
end
```

Comment: what's `h` in the `unique(h) ;` line?

Comment: I edited h variable as ut

Answer (score 0):

The Mathworks web site has examples of how to write an animated gif using imwrite:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94495-how-can-i-create-animated-gif-images-in-matlab and https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#btv452g-1

Basically, after drawnow you can save the figure window as an image, and then write the images to an animated gif file.

If you prefer a movie there's information on that as well:  https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.html

Comment: I don't understand this example. I haven't done it yet. I don't understand how to integrate. Also I found M_Map toolbox